# Unable detect changes to Microsoft documents using filesystemwatcher

Tags: c#, .net, filesystemwatcher

I have researched quite a bit on the internet but unable to get a solution to this issue.
Here is my code :

```
 m_Watcher.Filter = "*.*";
 m_Watcher.Path = settings.FolderName;
 m_Watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = true;
 m_Watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastWrite | NotifyFilters.FileName | NotifyFilters.DirectoryName;
 m_Watcher.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
 m_Watcher.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnCreated);                                
 m_Watcher.Renamed += new RenamedEventHandler(OnRenamed);
 m_Watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
```

Whenever I make changes to a word or excel file too many temporary files get generated all of which are hidden and so far I have only managed to ignore these temp and hidden files at execution time and unable to detect the changes made to the actual file. How may I do this?

Comment: Maybe change `Filter` to `"*.docx"` instead of `"*.*"`?

Comment: actually I have set this watcher to detect changes to all kind of files . so if I set filter to only a single type of file won't that stop detecting changes to other type of files ?

Comment: Hmmm why are you interested in these other files when _"unable to detect the changes made to the **actual file**"_.  Anyway, if there are _too many_ changes, FSW may miss some events.  See links to right

Comment: perhaps I wasn't clear . I want to detect changes to any file that is editable like text file, PowerPoint file and excel file

Comment: Microsoft Office programs never make changes to a file.  Far too risky, a mishap will leave the user with a destroyed document and no backup.  NotifyFilters.FileName tells you when it *replaces* the original document file.  There will be more than one, you have to know the original name.